# Reg Ex question

Tags: regex

What does the following reg ex code mean?

```
'/^\w{4,20}$/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that string should contain from 4 to 20 word characters (letters, digits, and underscores). Here:

- `^` (caret) matches at the start of the string the regex pattern is applied to. Matches a position rather than a character. Most regex flavors have an option to make the caret match after line breaks (i.e. at the start of a line in a file) as well
- `$` (dollar) matches at the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to. Matches a position rather than a character. Most regex flavors have an option to make the dollar match before line breaks (i.e. at the end of a line in a file) as well. Also matches before the very last line break if the string ends with a line break
- `\w` shorthand character class matching word characters (letters, digits, and underscores). Can be used inside and outside character classes.
- `{n,m}` where `n >= 0` and `m >= n` Repeats the previous item between n and m times. Greedy, so repeating m times is tried before reducing the repetition to n times

Let me show you a usage example. Say, we have the file with the following contents:

```
[spongebob@conductor /tmp]$ cat file.txt
between4and20
therearetoomanyalphanumcharacters
foo
okay
```

Now you want to get only those strings which match your pattern `'/^\w{4,20}$/'`:

```
[spongebob@conductor /tmp]$ grep -E '^\w{4,20}$' blah
between4and20
okay
```

On output you see only those lines, which fulfil your regular expression.

Ah, also, don't confuse `^` (caret) with `^` immediately after the opening `[`, the latter negates the character class, causing it to match a single character not listed in the character class. (Specifies a caret if placed anywhere except after the opening [), for example `[^a-d]` matches `x` (any character except `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`).

Comment: can you break it down for me to what exactly means what?

Answer (score 3):

It means:

- ^ Between the beginning,
- $ and the end of a given string,
- \w{4,20} there should be only 4-20 Alphanumeric characters (like
  a,b,c,d,1,2,3...etc, and also _)

I think you'll find [Wikipedia's page on Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions) a big, big help while learning regexes.

And just so there is no confusion, `^` and `$` don't necessarily need each other,
If the regex was:

`'/^\w{4,20}/'`

That'd mean: The match should be at the **start** of the string, followed by 4-20 alphanumeric characters.

Example (match in bold): **Foobar** baz

And if the regex pattern was:

`'/\w{4,20}$/'`

That'd mean: The match should be at the **end** of the string, proceeded by 4-20 alpha-numeric characters

Example (match in bold): Foo **barbaz**

Answer (score 1):

```
/ opening delimiter    
    ^ = start of sting
    \w = word character
    {x,y} min max
    $ = end of string 
/end delimiter
```